# Reverse a generic collection in Java

Tags: java, generics, collections, reverse

I've got the following task:

"Declare a method, expecting a Collection and reverse it in your method. Return the same collection given, do not return a new collection!.

```
static <T> void  reverse (Collection<T> collection)
```

Do not try to use Collections.reverse. It works only for a List, and not for collections"

My initial idea was something of the following:

```
public static <T> void reverse(Collection<T> collection){

    int size = collection.size();
    Iterator<T> iter = collection.iterator();
    Iterator<T> iter2 = collection.iterator();

    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
        collection.add(iter.next());
        iter2.remove();
    }
}
```

But I keep getting weird exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
at ReverseCollection.reverse(ReverseCollection.java:16)
at ReverseCollection.main(ReverseCollection.java:25)
```

Any idea how this should be done?

Comment: It appears the actual class implementing Collection whose instance you passed to your method doesn't support `add` operation. For example, the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` is a List that doesn't support `add`.

Comment: Sounds like they want you to use the command `Collections.swap()` - however this only works on Lists.

Comment: Who set you this task? It's meaningless and impossible. Collections in general are not ordered, which is precisely why the existing `reverse` and `swap` methods only accept lists.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! The task was not assigned to me by anyone in particular. I was just solving some Java problems so I can get better. Thanks for the quick response though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do cannot be done, since many `Collection` classes (for example `HashSet`) do not let you control the order.

The problem is that the order of elements in a general `Collection` is not defined. For example, think of a `Set`, which does not guarantee the order of the elements.
Since there is no ordering, it is hard to define what the reverse order is.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the task's requirements are just messed up. Probably they meant a collection that supports order like for example ArrayList. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the task is generally impossible (e.g. for immutable collections, and collections which do not iterate in insertion order), you can reverse any collection in which insertion order is preserved and the optional `clear` and `addAll` are implemented as follows:

```
<T, C extends Collection<T>> C reverse(C in) {
  // Copy the contents of the collection into a new list.
  List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(in);

  // Remove everything from the original container.
  in.clear();

  // Reverse the list.
  Collections.reverse(list);

  // Put everything back into the original container.
  in.addAll(list);
  // If addAll is not supported, but add is, you can do
  // for (T t : list) { in.add(t); }

  return in;
}
```

For collections where insertion order is not preserved, this may or may not result in a different ordering (e.g. it could be different for a `HashSet`; it would not be different for a `TreeSet`).